# Achieving suitable ZIndex or absolute position in wpf

Tags: wpf, xaml

Inside of an `Expander` i have a `stack panel` which is responsible for carrying other controls. This specified `Expander` is loaded in a grid. The problem is when i expand it, its content is covered behind the grid and can not be seen. 
I tried to increase the `ZIndex` of the inner stack panel in order to force it to overcome the grid but it didn't work.

I also searched about Absolute position (according to my background in HTML and CSS) and found some articles which talks about using canvas!

It seems canvas can totally be good and has been designed for this purpose, if all your elements has been placed inside it but as i said my main layout is a grid.

> Normally the Z-Order of elements ***inside*** a canvas is specified by the
>   order in XAML. But you can override the natural Z-Order by explicitly
>   defining a Canvas.ZIndex on the element.

So what should i do to achieve my goal ?

**This part is loaded inside a grid's column.**

```
<Grid>
  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Expander Background="White" Header="More Options">
        <StackPanel Width="150" Height="25">
            <CheckBox Margin="4" Content="Option 1" />
            <CheckBox Margin="4" Content="Option 2" />
            <CheckBox Margin="4" Content="Option 3" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Expander>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you set the height on the StackPanel to 25. Leave the StackPanel Height unset and it will work:

```
  <Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Expander Background="White" Header="More Options">
      <StackPanel Width="150">
        <CheckBox Margin="4" Content="Option 1" />
        <CheckBox Margin="4" Content="Option 2" />
        <CheckBox Margin="4" Content="Option 3" />
      </StackPanel>
    </Expander>
  </Grid>
```